# IPSec - Internet Layer Development

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, ipsec

Hi guys I need to create my own implementation of IPSec ( creating my own VPN ). Upon doing some searches found out that IPSec is under the Internet Layer of the Internet Protocol Suite. This means that it is with IPV4 / IPV6 Level.

I've also been reading some windows driver kit development samples since the application I need to create must run under windows. Can someone point out me out how can I start with the development?

Comment: IP, Internet Protocol, is a Network level Protocol, Internet Layer does not mean anything, you probably meant network level or network layer...

Comment: Are you going to develop a driver with C#? And do you really need your own IPSec implementation?

Comment: @Andrey Atapin I was planning to do this with C# but I guess managed code can't do this so I'll be using C/C++. Yes I really need to do no my own ipsec implementation part of my research.

Comment: @DavidePiras I just read it on wiki that IPSec is under Internet Layer. Technicality does not matter, I just need some jumpstart / proper guidance where how I can start my development. :D

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:
1. Try to find a real reason why not to reuse existing libraries.
2. Consider not using c# and .NET for such low level protocol staff.

The best way to start and understand the complexity is to take on of the open source implementations and try to read and understand the code.

Comment: Thanks. All the opensource project I found on the net is written for linux/opensource os. I need to create it under windows as part of my research. I'll be creating my own vpn implementation. I will not have any problem with VPN client since windows 7 support IPSec already. Actually I have a working setup of windows 7 client connecting to StrongSwan on my Ubuntu. I want to create my own setup like this one.

Comment: I see. Research is usually the best legitimization when reinventing the wheel. Have you already looked answers to this Q&A [Implementing IPSec in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960802/implementing-ipsec-protocol-in-java)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that question already that is why I've been reading some windows driver kit samples but I don't know yet if I can really implement my own IPSec using it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cipe-win32/) project can be entry point

Taken from the page:

Implements a Windows NT VPN peer to Olaf Titz's CIPE VPN for Linux